# R create an array of dates

Tags: arrays, r, date

I need to create an array of dates

```
a<-array(0,c(10,10))
```

Now, this command will create an array of numeric values.

Later on, when I assign date, like "2012-01-01" into each cell of this 10 by 10 array, it will turn into numeric value, which will force me to format them using

```
as.Date(a,origin="1970-01-01")
```

I would like to avoid this, and define a as an array of dates.

Do you guys know how?

W

Comment: You can call just `as.Date(a)` .

Comment: `as.Date(a, origin="1970-01-01")` is a vector, not a matrix/array though. A `matrix` cannot contain non-atomic classed R objects (see `?matrix`).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, I understood that, but interestingly, I could also as.Date(a[[g]],origin="1970-01-01"), if a is defined as a list. Do you know why that works? But of course, this is off my question here, just curious.